# Zend Framework php error

Tags: php, zend-framework

Were currently trying to host an existing website on a new local server. I'm quite new to zend but have some experience in php.

this is the error code i get

```
Warning: require_once(../../Statement/Pdo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Hg/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 33

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../../Statement/Pdo.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.26/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Hg/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 33
```

The pdo.php file links up fine in phpstorm. I haven't a clue whats up with this now.

Any help would be greatful

Cheers!

Comment: Does the file exist on that path? If yes, could it be a permission problem? Also, ZF never uses `../../` in its requires, which suggests your copy of the framework has been modified (not generally a good idea). This may or may not be related to the underlying problem.

Comment: IT does link up, Like i said the phpstorm linked it up fine. all the permissions have been set to 777 just to check if it'd work which is hasn't.